# TrustStoreManager.java:161|Inaccessible trust store

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jvm, jvm-arguments

I have a .jks file and set the JVM arguments as

```
-Djavax.net.debug=all -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=<path to .jks>/truststore_lab.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

so that my program will use the .jks file as the truststore.

But when I run the program it will say

```
Inaccessible trust store: <path to .jks>/truststore_lab.jks
```

and it will use the default truststore in`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.16.1.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts`

I copy-pasted the path so the path to .jks should be correct and I have no idea why my program cannot use the .jks file as the truststore

Here is debug output

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djavax.net.debug=all -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/Users/kburkholder/Documents/truststore_lab.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
2022-09-16 10:42:20.127  INFO [pay-evc-issuance,,,] 60220 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7274d2cc] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2022-09-16 10:42:20.341 PDT|SSLContextImpl.java:428|System property jdk.tls.client.cipherSuites is set to 'null'
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2022-09-16 10:42:20.342 PDT|SSLContextImpl.java:428|System property jdk.tls.server.cipherSuites is set to 'null'
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2022-09-16 10:42:20.368 PDT|SSLCipher.java:464|jdk.tls.keyLimits:  entry = AES/GCM/NoPadding KeyUpdate 2^37. AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE = 137438953472
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2022-09-16 10:42:20.373 PDT|SSLContextImpl.java:402|Ignore disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2022-09-16 10:42:20.373 PDT|SSLContextImpl.java:411|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
...
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2022-09-16 10:42:20.386 PDT|SSLContextImpl.java:402|Ignore disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2022-09-16 10:42:20.386 PDT|SSLContextImpl.java:411|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2022-09-16 10:42:20.388 PDT|TrustStoreManager.java:161|Inaccessible trust store: /Users/kburkholder/Documents/NOVA/pay-evc-issuance/issuance-webservice/dist/truststore_lab.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2022-09-16 10:42:20.388 PDT|TrustStoreManager.java:112|trustStore is: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.16.1.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts
trustStore type is: jks
trustStore provider is:
```

Comment: Are you using relative path for the JKS ? Have you tried using file:<path>